# Create a unique four digit code from 35 characters

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to generate a four digit code based on the code generated before it, starting at 0000 and going to zzzz.

These are the available characters to be inside the code:

```
private static final char[] _availableChar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

The first thing I do is the get the newest code or the code with the highest `auto_incremented` Id.

I then pass that to this function to generate the next cod:

```
private String getNewCodeFromOldCode(String oldCode) {
        char[] newCodeChars = oldCode.toCharArray();

        if (oldCode == null || oldCode.isEmpty()) {
            return "0000";
        } else {
            char[] oldCodeChars = oldCode.toCharArray();

            if (oldCodeChars[3] != 'z') {
                newCodeChars[3] = _availableChar[String.valueOf(_availableChar).indexOf(oldCodeChars[3]) + 1];
            } else {

                if (oldCodeChars[2] != 'z') {
                    newCodeChars[3] = '0';
                    newCodeChars[2] = _availableChar[String.valueOf(_availableChar).indexOf(oldCodeChars[2]) + 1];
                } else {

                    if (oldCodeChars[1] != 'z') {
                        newCodeChars[2] = '0';
                        newCodeChars[1] = _availableChar[String.valueOf(_availableChar).indexOf(oldCodeChars[1]) + 1];
                    } else {

                        if (oldCodeChars[0] != 'z') {
                            newCodeChars[1] = '0';
                            newCodeChars[0] = _availableChar[String.valueOf(_availableChar).indexOf(oldCodeChars[0]) + 1];
                        } else {
                            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Unable To Generate A Code");
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(newCodeChars);
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure how to calculate the permutations but I think I have upwards of million different perm. available.

Answer (score 5):

By my count, 0-9 + a-z gives 36 characters rather than 35.

For four digits like that, the number of combinations is \$36^4\$, which works out to 1,679,616.

As for the code itself, I think I'd do things just a little differently. What you really have is a 4-digit number in base 36. It's probably easiest to just use a normal number, and then use toString to generate the base-36 representation when you need it:

```
Integer counter;
String result = toString(counter, 36);
```

This does differ in one minor detail: it won't fill in leading zeros, so if it's shorter than 4 characters, you'll have to fill in the leading zeros yourself (still a pretty trivial operation though).

For the sake of security, I don't install Java on my machines, but there's a rough imitation of the basic idea, but in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <cassert>

// This should be approximately equivalent to what you'd get from 
// Java's `toString`, at least for non-negative numbers:
std::string toString(unsigned value, unsigned base) {
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    assert(base <= 36);

    std::deque<char> ret;

    while (value) {
        unsigned digit = value % base;
        value /= base;
        ret.push_front(digits[digit]);
    }
    return std::string(ret.begin(), ret.end());
}

// This calls toString, then pads the result out to 4 digits.
std::string paddedToString(unsigned value, unsigned base, unsigned num_digits) {
    std::string s = toString(value, base);

    // Add enough 0's to get to the desired width:
    return std::string(num_digits - s.size(), '0') + s;
}

// A quick test of the code.    
int main() { 
    // First we'll write the first few values:
    for (unsigned value = 0; value < 256; value++) 
        std::cout << paddedToString(value, 36, 4) << "\t";

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Then some values from around the middle of the range:
    unsigned base = 512 * 1024;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        std::cout << paddedToString(i + base, 36, 4) << "\t";
}
```

Comment: what's the implementation of the `toString(counter, 36)`?

Comment: @lxcky: It's in the standard library. At a guess, it probably uses modulus and division to separate out one digit at a time, and uses that to index into an array of char to pick what to display for each digit.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean by **4-digit number in base 36**. In the real world application Users are going to have to  paint this 4 letter code onto a finished product. This will still be less than four characters?

Comment: @SamOrozco: As I said: "if it's shorter than 4 characters, you'll have to fill in the leading zeros yourself". One easy way to do this would be to start with `"000"`, and concatenate the result from `toString` to the end, then take the last four characters of that resulting string.

Comment: I understand that. Excuse me if this is simple but I don't understand the whole base 36 number and how that gets converted to a string like this.

Comment: @SamOrozco: I've added some code that (I hope) clarifies the situation somewhat.

Comment: @lxcky: For what it's worth, I've added some (C++) code that shows at least a rough idea of one way `toString` could be implemented (though Java doesn't have unsigned numbers, so at the very least its implementation also needs to handle negative numbers).